# Make DIV fill remainder of page vertically?

Tags: css, html

I have a Google Maps app that takes up most of the page.  However, I need to reserve the top-most strip of space for a menu bar.  How can make the map div automatically fill its vertical space?  `height: 100%` does not work because the top bar will then push the map past the bottom of the page.

```
+--------------------------------+
|      top bar  (n units tall)   |
|================================|
|              ^                 |
|              |                 |
|             div                |
|     (100%-n units tall)        |
|              |                 |
|              v                 |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: if x = 10%, then put div{height:90%}

Comment: The bottom div needs to dynamically resize.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use absolute positioning.

**HTML**

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>
    This is where the content starts.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
BODY
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#content
{
    border: 3px solid #971111;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #DDD;
    padding-top: 85px;
}
#header
{
    border: 2px solid #279895;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

By positioning `#content` absolutely and specifying the top, right, bottom, and left properties, you get a div taking up the entire viewport.

Then you set `padding-top` on `#content` to be >= the height of `#header`.

Finally, place `#header` inside `#content` and position it absolutely (specifying top, left, right, and the height).

**I'm not sure how browser friendly this is.** Check out [this article at A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/) for more information.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this trick. You should mention, though, that it doesn't work in IE6.

Comment: I did. In bold. Read the article I cited - it explains a workaround for IE6 =)

Comment: But this requires you hard-code the height of the header, right?

Comment: You are correct. It also requires you to hard code the top padding of `#content` to be >= `#header`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it correctly positions using CSS only. Browser compatibility might not be the best but it's the best we've got. It makes absolutely no sense that simple layouts like this would require javascript.

Comment: and how do you fill the height if you have a variable header height that you dont know?

Comment: @Manticore - I think tables, flexbox, or JS are your only options.

Answer (score 11):

The way to do it, apparently, is to use JavaScript to monitor the onload and onresize events and programmatically resize the filling div like so:

Using jQuery:

```
function resize() {
    $("#bottom").height($(document).height() - $('#top').height());
}
```

Using plain JavaScript:

```
function resize() {
    document.getElementById("bottom").style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - headerHeight) + "px";
}
```

**Edit:** and then bind these to the `window` object.

Comment: resize doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229010/jquery-resize-not-working-at-firefox-chrome-and-safari

Answer (score 9):

Another solution not given uses CSS3 rather than javascript.  There is a calc() function now which can be used to do the same thing:

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="header">
        Header
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        Bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS3**

```
#content {
    height: 300px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 30px;
}
#bottom {
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sean_s_butler/95Cn7/)

You might also want to look into using the `box-sizing: border-box` style for interior divs since this can get rid of problems of padding and borders poking outside of parent divs.

Comment: What if the height of `#header` is not fixed to 30px?

Comment: calc() is super useful!

Answer (score 3):

If you [calculate the page position of the div element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5601659/453605) you can do without knowing the header element:

```
function resize() {
    var el = $("#bottom");
    el.height($(document).height() - el.offset().top);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to try  [jquery-layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) plugin. You will see a bunch of demos and examples on the link.

I don't know if you are familiar with the concepts of [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) or some other Javascript helper framework, like [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/) or [Mootools](http://mootools.net/) but it's a vital idea to use one of them. They are hide most browser-related tricks from the programmer and they have a number of useful extension for UI, DOM manipulation, etc.

Comment: I agree!  Let a jquery handle this for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var sizeFooter = function(){
    $(".webfooter").css("padding-bottom", "0px").css("padding-bottom", $(window).height() - $("body").height())
}
$(window).resize(sizeFooter);
```