# understanding <div> behaviour

Tags: css, html

With refrence to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898221/make-div-fill-remainder-of-page-vertically) and the accepted answer, I tried doing something similar.

```
.Content
{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 padding-top:75px;
 width:inherit;
 height:inherit;
}

.Header
{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 height:75px;
 width:inherit;
 background-color:Blue;
 text-align:center;
}

<form id="form1" runat="server" style="width:100%;height:100%">
 <div id="Content" class="Content">
  <div id="Header" class="Header">
   <h1 style="color:White">Report Portal</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

I want the content area to fill the entire page, no more. But vertical scroll bars appear for the web page with the above html. How can I correct that?

Comment: wat you want i didnt get .....

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/Ddffh/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't make the header absolute also remove the `padding-top: 75px`.

Consider this fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aKNB8/)

EDIT: Updated fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aKNB8/1/)

Comment: i think this is the better answer, as the others will have the sideeffect that text inside content will overlap with the header.
EDIT: Misread the answer a bit... i think the right course of action would be to just remove absolute positioning from the content div.
this will preserver the proper 75px padding and remove the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have width and height set to 100% on the body and hmtl?

Also, the padding is creating a vertical scrollbar, remove this and it will work as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/MqKXH/

Comment: removing the padding is resolving the problem. But i dont have width and and height set to 100% on body and html. Is that necessary?

Comment: Yes, this is necessary for the inner elements to behave as you intend. Just like my example shows.

Answer (score 0):

You have put     Height > inherit for "Content".

CSS Inheritance  (http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/inheritance/)

CSS inheritance works on a property by property basis. When applied to an element in a document, a property with the value 'inherit' will use the same value as the parent element has for that property.

Overall, "Content" height is already 100% of the browser which is inherited from "form" tag. After adding padding from top ie "75px" ..its total height becomes "browser height + 75px". It reasons to scroll the page.

Solution :
1] Avoid the top padding to "Content". Give that padding to its inner container
2] use style

```
body, html{
overflow:hidden;
}
```