# Dynamically position bottom elements vertically with HTML5 and CSS

Tags: css, html, position

I've got a fairly simple page where I want to create something like this:

[------------------div - 100px filler color-----------------]
[------------------h1 - height 100px----------------------]
[--------------- div - 100%-(100px+100px)-------------]

The HTML I'm working with is:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
    </div>

    <h1>Big Old Text</h1>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

The CSS is:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.background {
/*  background: url(rotate.php) no-repeat center fixed; */
    background: url(background_image_05.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#header {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.10);
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

h1 {
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    font-size: 72px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,255,0.10);
}
```

I don't want any scroll bars. I tried to modify a version of this earlier [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898221/make-div-fill-remainder-of-page-vertically), but it's not quite working out the way I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to understand what you are looking for...

**HTML**:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <h1>Big Old Text</h1>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}

body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#content{
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    bottom:100px;
    border:red 2px solid;
}​
```

You could also see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dZEQQ/3/

I hope this is what you are looking for(pay attention to #content styles).