# jQuery-UI resizable, programatically resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to resize a div with jquery and have the alsoResize trigger:
I tried changing the width and then triggering the resize event, but it doesnt work.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ns3yn/2/

Thanks!

Comment: What's not working? Looks right to me.

Comment: The picture isnt being resized (updated fiddle to make it more clear)

Comment: you're declared the resizable correctly, as you can see when you use the mouse to resize. The way you're trying to trigger it programatically doesn't work.

Comment: @BZink why does the `width()` function not fire a resize event ? i would have thought it should work without the `trigger('resize')` ?

Comment: Found my answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229010/jquery-resize-not-working-at-firefox-chrome-and-safari resize doesnt work on DIVs - works on Windows / Frames ... this is why its not working

Comment: Yeah. Me too. It seems that the UI widget is binding the control to mouse related event handlers, and not the CSS change.

Comment: @BZink yep - got to the same conclusion ....

Comment: @BZink how do i do this then?

Comment: @chacham15 have a look at my answer - add the IMG to the selector on the width change

Comment: @ManseUK is there any way to do it the way that I want though?

Comment: @chacham15 yes CSS - updated my answer ...

Answer (score 2):

This issue is an interesting one.  My need required me to resize many "alsoResize" objects along with resizing the original object.

For one, it is a requested jQuery UI feature:
[Resizable: Expose an API for programatically triggering a resize](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5426)

But, until that is implemented, in lieu of creating this feature myself, I have found a pretty decent quick solution.  The solution comes from here:
[Programmatically Resize a resizable element](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-programmatically-resize-a-resizable-element)

The solution uses some jquery unit testing libraries that simulate a mouse drag.  You can find the necessary libraries here:
[jquery.simulate.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/jquery.simulate.js)
[resizable_test_helpers.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/tests/unit/resizable/resizable_test_helpers.js)

So include those two files above, then you can run code like this:

```
var handle = ".ui-resizable-se";
TestHelpers.resizable.drag(handle, 50, 50);
```

This will programatically resize your object by 50 pixels right and down.

Comment: I think it's actually the best solution for unit testing resizable event.

Answer (score 0):

Because nowhere says that the resizable plugin use the resize event to trigger changes. All you need is add .add('img') after window selector to have the expected result

Comment: thats not the point, the point is seperating the code which resizes all the subelements and the code that resizes the whole

Answer (score 0):

.trigger("resize") doesn't actually  trigger the resize event.

If you bind explicitly to the event you'll see this...

```
$(".window").bind("resize", function(){
   alert("resize event");

});
```

Comment: seems that you're incorrect: http://jsfiddle.net/Ns3yn/7/ To be more specific, as I read in the doc: divs can still receive the event if they are manually triggered.